# Custom plugin in cordova for android

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am using cordova in my android application and I want to use my custom plugins.
But I am getting error- **exec() call to unknown plugin**

this is my `HTML` file.

```
function callNativePlugin( returnSuccess ) {
    HelloPlugin.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess );
}

function nativePluginResultHandler (result) {
    alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
}

function nativePluginErrorHandler (error) {
    alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
}

function newCall(){
    alert("function  ready");
    window.echo = function(str, callback) {
        cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
            callback('Nothing to echo.');
        }, "HelloPlugin", "echo", [str]);
    };
    window.echo("echome", function(echoValue) {
        alert(echoValue == "echome"); // should alert true.
    });
}
           </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <button onclick="newCall();">Click to invoke the Native Plugin with an SUCCESS!</button>
    <button onclick="callNativePlugin('error');">Click to invoke the Native Plugin with an ERROR!</button>

</body>
```

this is my `js` file

```
var HelloPlugin = {

    callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) {
        return cordova.exec(success, fail, "com.webview.HelloPlugin", "HelloPlugin", [resultType]);
    }
};
```

Plugin `java` file

```
public class HelloPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Log.i("Log msg","Log msg");
        return false;
    }
}
```

my `Config.js` file

```
<feature name="HelloPlugin">
    <param name="com.webview.HelloPlugin" value="com.ecsoftware.HelloPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Comment: my Confid.js   <feature name="HelloPlugin">
    <param name="com.webview.HelloPlugin" value="com.ecsoftware.HelloPlugin" />
</feature>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `config.xml` should look like this:

```
<feature name="com.webview.HelloPlugin"> 
    <param name="android-package" value="com.ecsoftware.HelloPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Also remember this is the `config.xml` file in your `res/xml/` folder (and not the one in the `www` folder).